# Storing 2 same id of post table with different language into database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, multilingual

I'm building a multi language website. In this case just 2 languages, it's Indonesian and English using Laravel.
I have posts table, it will store id of each post and post_translations table is to store local, title, and description of post.
I got the problem when storing data into database. I don't have any idea how to store post without inc the id except I've added 2 same post with Indonesian and English.

This is the result (wrong)

**posts table**

```
id 
1
2
```

**post_translations table**

```
id  post_id  locale   title
1     1      en       fisrt post
2     2      id       post yang pertama
```

Expexted result

**posts table**

```
id 
1
```

**post_translations table**

```
id  post_id  locale   title
1     1      en       fisrt post
2     1      id       post yang pertama
```

**PostController**

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required'
    ]);

    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->slug = $request->slug;
    $post->content = $request->content;

    $post->save();
    return redirect()->route('post.index');
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

Comment: @Indra I use that package. I really don't know how to insert the data.

Comment: @lolagi what's your problem store or retrieval?

Comment: @lolagi then please give us all the information. What's the table structure, what packages you use and what you tried so we can help you.

Comment: @Indra I follow this tutorial. All of the information's here 
  https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-for-your-laravel-application

Comment: @Indra I've just added on my repo https://github.com/sufita/multi-language

Comment: @lolagi hey, I saw your comment just now. I will try to answer asap

Comment: @Indra Thank you. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here we go (please note that this is not the only way):

1. install spatie/laravel-translatable with

   composer require spatie/laravel-translatable

**Note: for native spatie/laravel-translatable go to version 2 **

2. create a table with this structure:

   CREATE TABLE `articles` (
     `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
     `slug` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
     `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
     `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Note: beter use a migration. I just exported a table I did earlier to test

3. Insert the data in the datatabase in json format like this:

```html
    INSERT INTO `pages` (`id`, `title`, `slug`, `content`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
        (1, '{"ro":"Acas\\u0103","en":"Home"}', NULL, '{"ro":"<p><strong>Test title<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n\\r\\n<p>Test content romanian<\\/p>\\r\\n","en":"<p><strong>test title english<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n\\r\\n<p>test content english.<\\/p>\\r\\n"}', '2017-04-03 11:45:56', '2017-04-03 12:15:16');
```

4. Now create the blade to edit, update, create show etc. To get the language do something like this in the blade:

   {{ $data->title }}

   {!! nl2br($data->content) !!}
5. And in the controller:
   add something like this:

   /**
            * Generate the field by language
            *
            * @param   Model        $entry      the item selected from the database
            *
             * @return  array
            */

   ```
   public function getTranslatableFields($fields)
   {
       $inputs = [];
       $languages = $this->getLanguages();

       foreach ($languages as $language) {
           foreach ($fields as $field) {
               $inputs[] = [
                   'name' => "{$field['name']}[{$language->abbr}]",
                   'label' => $field['label'] . " ($language->abbr)",
                   'lang' => $language->abbr,
                   'type' => array_key_exists('type', $field) ?     $field['type'] : 'text'
               ];
           }
       }

       return $inputs;
   }
   ```

I added this function in a LangTrait. Since I also use backpack for laravel I did some more things.

For edit I added this method in the trait:

```
/**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param   int             $id             the item's identifier
     *
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {    
        $data['entry'] = Model::find($id);
        $data['title'] = trans('lang_file.edit').' '.$this->entity_name; // name of the page 
        $data['fields'] = $this->getMultiLangFields($data['entry']);
        $data['id'] = $id;

        return view('crud::edit', $data);
    }


/**
     * Generate the field by language
     *
     * @param   Model        $entry      the item selected from the database
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    protected function getMultiLangFields($entry)
    {
        $fields['id'] = ['name' => 'id', 'type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $entry->id];

        foreach ($this->crud->update_fields as $key => $field) {
            $value = null;

            if (array_key_exists('lang', $field)) {
                $name = preg_replace('/(\[\w{2}\])$/i', '', $field['name']);
                $value = $entry->getTranslation($name, $field['lang']);
            }

            $fields[$key] = array_merge($field, ['value' => $value]);
        }

        return $fields;
    }



/**
     * Get the application active languages
     *
     * @return  \Backpack\LangFileManager\app\Models\Language
     */
    protected function getLanguages()
    {
        return Language::whereActive(1)->orderBy('default', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

6. Finally in my main controller I did:
   **use LangTrait;** (contains everything above)

In construct I added this:

```
$this->getTranslatableFields($fields)
```

where $fields it's the list of fields I need

All methods should be adapted to you html format. As I said I use backpack for laravel and fields are formatted accordingly

7. And finally for the getLanguage file to work I created a new table and a model in the DB:

Model:

```
class Language extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'languages';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'flag', 'abbr', 'native', 'active', 'default'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function getActiveLanguagesArray()
    {
        $active_languages = self::where('active', 1)->get()->toArray();
        $localizable_languages_array = [];

        if (count($active_languages)) {
            foreach ($active_languages as $key => $lang) {
                $localizable_languages_array[$lang['abbr']] = $lang;
            }

            return $localizable_languages_array;
        }

        return config('laravellocalization.supportedLocales');
    }

    public static function findByAbbr($abbr = false)
    {
        return self::where('abbr', $abbr)->first();
    }
}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `abbr` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `script` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `native` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `default` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Data in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `languages` (`id`, `name`, `app_name`, `flag`, `abbr`, `script`, `native`, `active`, `default`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`) VALUES
(1, 'English', 'english', '', 'en', 'Latn', 'English', 1, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Romanian', 'romanian', '', 'ro', 'Latn', 'română', 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Since I did this through a package I kind of messed around a little bit with the code.

---

**Now, for the spatie/laravel-translatable package version**:

1. set up the service provider in config/app.php add this in the providers array:

   Spatie\Translatable\TranslatableServiceProvider::class,

In the model Articles add `use HasTranslations;` like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;

class NewsItem extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name']; // list the columns you want to be translatable (will have json format)
}
```

2. save a new entry and use it:

   $article = new Article;
   $article->setTranslation('name', 'en', 'Updated name in English')
           ->setTranslation('name', 'nl', 'Naam in het Nederlands');

   $article->save();

   $article->name; // Returns 'Name in English' given that the current app locale is 'en'
   $article->getTranslation('name', 'nl'); // returns 'Naam in het Nederlands'

   app()->setLocale('nl');

   $article->name; // Returns 'Naam in het Nederlands'
3. examples from: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable
4. Database table format is as stated above in the first version

If it does not work out let me know and I'll look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your tables  strucuture:

**posts** : *id, slug*.

**post_translations** : *id, post_id, locale, title, content*

Also add relation to your Post model:

```
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostTranslation::class, 'post_id');
}
```

And update your controller:

```
$post = new Post;

$post->slug = $request->slug;
$post->save();

$post->translations()->create([
    'locale' => 'en', //or grab it from $request
    'title' => $request->title,
    'content' => $request->content
])
```

It will create your post and add translation to it